# 2012 Mazda3 shifts gears but won't move

Tags: clutch, mazda, manual-transmission, mazda-3

My car was shifting fine. All of a sudden I attempted to slow down for traffic, depressed the clutch to downshift and nothing happened. Coasted to side road. Attempted to depress the clutch and I put it in 1st gear but the car just revved but wouldn't move. None of the gears including reverse worked. Car will rev up.

Clutch depresses easily and comes back up very easy as well. Could this be a cable problem, or does it sound like the clutch is gone?

Help!!

Comment: Does the pedal feel any different? Is there any fluid under the car? Does it feel like the car is even trying to move a little bit?

Answer (score 7):

If the clutch cable was bad you wouldn't be able to put in in gear with the engine running. Based on what you have described you have a bad clutch.

Answer (score 5):

If you can depress the pedal and select gears with the engine running, but then don't have any drive once you have selected a gear, then I'm afraid it sounds very much like the clutch has gone.

It's also possible that there has been a failure elsewhere in the transmission, but a clutch failure is probably more likely - other failures tend to make themselves known with loud noises...